# undefined reference to function that is already defined

Tags: c, eclipse, ibm-cloud, undefined-reference, iot

Currently trying to build a project in eclipse. The project explorer is shown below:

[image]

In `cabbie.c` I get the error, `undefined reference to initialize...`, in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../iotfclient.h"

Iotfclient client;
int rc;

int main() {
    /* Setup your example here, code that should run once
     */

    rc = initialize(&client, "h7dzt2", "Edison_cabquam", "notwindows95", "token", "Over_9000");

    /* Code in this loop will run repeatedly
     */
    for (;;) {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function is already defined in `iotfclient.h` which was included as a header file. Is it correct to define it as `../iotfclient.h`? Am I supposed to make a Makefile? The function prototype in `iotfclient.h` is given below:

```
int initialize(Iotfclient *client, char *orgId, char *deviceType, char *deviceId, char *authmethod, char *authtoken);
/**
* Function used to initialize the IBM Watson IoT client using the config file which is generated when you register your device
* @param client - Reference to the Iotfclient
* @param configFilePath - File path to the configuration file 
*
* @return int return code
* error codes
* CONFIG_FILE_ERROR -3 - Config file not present or not in right format
*/
```

This project is trying to connect the bluemix IOT Platform.

Comment: It's **declared** in `iotfclient.h`, but where is it **defined**?

Comment: Do you get warning on the #include line in you cabbie.c?

Comment: @ItayB I used to, when it was just `#include "iotfclient.h". Then I changed it to `"../iotfclient.h"`

Comment: @sunqingyao It was declared in `iotfclient.c`

Comment: the project is not correctly laid out.  ALL *.c files need to be under the `src` section.   ALL *.h files need to be under the `Includes` section.  You need to make those corrections.  Eclipse will not compile random files.  Place those files in the correct sections of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialize()` is **declared** in `iotfclient.h`. However, it's not necessary **defined**. In other words, the compiler knows identifier `initialise` stands for a function, but to create a program, you have also to tell the linker how the function works, that is, add the function body.

Try including `../iotfclient.c`.

Comment: NONONO dp not be #include'ing a *.c file.  Fix the layout of the project instead.

Comment: @user3629249 You're right, *.c files are not designed for being included. Maybe copying the relevant function definition from ioftclient.c to cabbie.c will be a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

The function `initialize` is **declared** in `../iotfclient.h`, it might be  **defined** in `../iotfclient.c`, but do you compile this file and link it to your project?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Can you please add that in your answer?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: not being an eclipse user, I don't know what kind of magic this IDE performs to implement the notion of *project*.  How do you build your program?  A Makefile would certainly help if you how to compose one and include it in the *project*.

Comment: There's a simple build button and then a run button

Comment: Look at the eclipse documentation to find out how you can put multiple source files in a *project* or how you can use a Makefile.